# How to check Daemonset scheduled and available numbers are equal with ansible k8s_info module

Tags: ansible

How can we check Daemonset desired number scheduled and available numbers are equal with ansible k8s_info module ?

DaemonSet status

```
  status:
    currentNumberScheduled: 12
    desiredNumberScheduled: 12
    numberAvailable: 12
    numberMisscheduled: 0
    numberReady: 12
    observedGeneration: 2
    updatedNumberScheduled: 12
```

Something like below

```
- name: "Wait for DaemonSet to be active"
  k8s_info:
    api_key: "{{ k8s_api_key }}"
    kind: DaemonSet
    api_version: apps/v1
    name: fluentd
    namespace: openshift-logging
  register: ds
  until:
  - ds.resources is defined
  - ds | json_query('resources[*].status.desiredNumberScheduled == resources[*].status.numberAvailable )  
  retries: 60
  delay: 10
```

Thanks
Raj

Comment: What error or bad outcome is that code producing for you?

Comment: fatal: [localhost]: FAILED! => {"msg": "The conditional check 'ds | json_query('resources[*].status.desiredNumberScheduled == resources[*].status.numberAvailable )' failed. The error was: template error while templating string: unexpected char \"'\" at 22. String: {% if ds | json_query('resources[*].status.desiredNumberScheduled == resources[*].status.numberAvailable ) %} True {% else %} False {% endif %}"}

Comment: I had presumed you left off the closing quote as a copy-paste here, but evidently you really did forget the closing quote. Also, I am not JMESPath expert, but I don't think that's legal jmespath (even if the quote was fixed)